# How to give user input to Django RestAPI using postman?

Tags: python, api, django-rest-framework

I have made an DjangoRestApi and giving user input using postman(POST method).but the error is

```
TypeError: Object of type 'JSONDecodeError' is not JSON serializable
```

it is showing in django server where i am going wrong please help Thanks

views.py

```
import spacy
from django.shortcuts import render,HttpResponse
from django.http import Http404
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.core import serializers
from django.conf import settings
import json  

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
@api_view(["POST"])
def nounphrases(requestdata):
    try:
        text = json.loads(requestdata.body)
        nounphrases = []
        for word in (nlp((text))):
            c = (word.lemma_)
            nounphrases.append(c)
            output = [{"nounphrases" : nounphrases  }]

        return JsonResponse(json.dumps(output))
    except ValueError as e:
        return Response(e,status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: The error has nothing to do with postman. It is because you are getting an error and passing the exception object itself to Response; you should pass `e.message` instead. But once you've fixed that, you should investigate why you are getting an error at all; and that is probably because you are doing things like manually trying to parse the request body rather than just accessing `request.data` directly.

Comment: What is the post request signature you are making through postman app?